# Can the electric field strength of a wire simply be calculated using the voltage / length formula?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields

Can the electric field strength of a wire simply be calculated using the voltage / length formula:

Electric Field Strength = Voltage Across Wire/ Length of Wire

I am asking about a wire with current running through it and not a charged wire.

Comment: To clarify, you're asking about a wire with current running through it, and not a charged wire (electrostatics)?

Comment: @BMS Yes, I am asking about a wire with current running through i and not a charged wire.

Comment: Got it. Please add that to your question text, as some won't read these comments prior to answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method for evaluating the electric field assumes it is appropriate to model it as spatially constant within the wire since you're basically taking a spatial average. You'll have to decide wether or not this is accurate.